# Sqlite: Create new table for query results and keep the original schema

Tags: c, database, sqlite, database-schema

I have the following db file (DB1.db) contains only one table:

```
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE CARS (ID INT KEY NOT NULL, COMPANY CHAR(20) NOT NULL, COLOR CHAR(10) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO "CARS" VALUES(111,'Hyundai','White');
INSERT INTO "CARS" VALUES(222,'BMW','Black');
INSERT INTO "CARS" VALUES(333,'Toyota','Blue');
COMMIT;
```

In order to join between two tables in two different databases, I attach the DB1.db (and the other db) into DB2.db:

```
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'DB1.db' AS 'db1' ;
```

The 'CARS' table info looks like:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(CARS);
0|ID|INT KEY|1||0
1|COMPANY|CHAR(20)|1||0
2|COLOR|CHAR(10)|1||0
```

Next and final, I want to run query on the attached tables and save the result in new table in DB2.db:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE RES1 AS SELECT ID,COMPANY FROM CARS WHERE ID='333';
```

And as I expected, the result is in a new table:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM RES1 ;
333|Toyota
```

But the new table info looks like:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(RES1);
0|ID|INT|0||0
1|COMPANY|TEXT|0||0
```

And as you can see, I lost the 'COMPANY' column type - it is no longer 'CHAR(20)' and the column might be empty ('NOT NULL' is 0 and not 1 as before).

**My question:**
How can I do the operations above (attach and query result into new table) and still not lose the original table information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ATTACHing.

CREATE TABLE … AS … does not keep the table definition; it creates a table with the bare minimum of type information to be able to store the values.

If you want to have any different table definition, you have to create the table manually, and then insert the data with [INSERT INTO … SELECT …](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).